# React Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
**this is the npm-debug.log**
```

I want to use bootstrap's js in react but the page show me  Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery,I have been download the jquery and I promise that I imported it before bootsrap.thanks.

```
npm-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.10.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle oa-system-app@0.1.0~prestart: oa-system-app@0.1.0
6 silly lifecycle oa-system-app@0.1.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle oa-system-app@0.1.0~start: oa-system-app@0.1.0
8 verbose lifecycle oa-system-app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle oa-system-app@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\workspaces\oa-system-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Windows\System32\;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ZJ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ZJ\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle oa-system-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: D:\workspaces\oa-system-app
11 silly lifecycle oa-system-app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
12 verbose stack Error: kill ENOSYS
12 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
12 verbose stack     at process.kill (internal/process.js:190:13)
12 verbose stack     at process.listener (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:86:15)
12 verbose stack     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
12 verbose stack     at process.emit (events.js:185:7)
12 verbose stack     at processEmit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:146:32)
12 verbose stack     at processEmit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:146:32)
12 verbose stack     at Signal.wrap.onsignal (internal/process.js:217:44)
13 verbose cwd D:\workspaces\oa-system-app
14 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
15 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
16 error node v6.10.2
17 error npm  v3.10.10
18 error code ENOSYS
19 error errno ENOSYS
20 error syscall kill
21 error kill ENOSYS
22 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
22 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
23 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
import 'jquery/src/jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```